# How to prevent a tag from deletion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-typeahead, bloodhound

I am using twitter typeaheadjs to populate tags on my page. I want to prevent a tag from deletion when tag value is equal to login id.

I got the event from [docs](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/):

Before item remove event:

```
$('input').on('beforeItemRemove', function(event) {
    alert("before item removed");
    var tag = event.item;
    if(tag == DataMixin.data.user.username){
        console.log('cannot delete agent');
    }else{
        console.log('agent deleted');
    }
 });
```

After item removed event:

```
$('input').on('itemRemoved', function (event) {
    alert("item removed");
        }
    }
});
```

How do I prevent tag deletion based on above condition in typeaheadJS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

> event.cancel: set to true to prevent the item getting removed

```
$('input').on('beforeItemRemove', function(event) {
    alert("before item removed");
    var tag = event.item;
    if(tag == DataMixin.data.user.username){
        event.cancel = true;
        console.log('cannot delete agent');
    }else{
        console.log('agent deleted');
    }
 });
```

Comment: just figured it out from the actual JS file(bootstrap-tagsinput.js) @line 195. Thanks anyways